# how to access "recover item folder" of archive mailbox?

Tags: exchange, email-server, microsoft-office-365

May I know from the user perspective, is it possible for them to access "recover item folder" of their archive mailbox?

I enable the archive mailbox for users, there is a "Recoverable Items 14 days Move to Archive" retention tag assigned to them. So how can they access the "recover item folder" of their archive mailbox themselves?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/recoverable-items-folder/recoverable-items-folder?view=exchserver-2019 Each user mailbox is divided into two subtrees: the IPM (interpersonal messaging) subtree, which contains the normal, visible folders such as Inbox, Calendar, and Sent Items and the non-IPM subtree, which contains internal data, preferences, and other operational data about the mailbox. The Recoverable Items folder resides in the non-IPM subtree of each mailbox. This subtree isn't visible to users using Outlook, Outlook on the web, or other email clients.

Comment: So how can they access the "recover item folder" of their archive mailbox themselves?

Comment: What about trying this https://www.howtogeek.com/396486/how-to-recover-deleted-items-from-outlook/